# Why a POST request uses the PSH flag in the first packet?

Tags: networking, http, tcp

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of the POST HTTP Transaction. When there is a GET request with a long URI that needs more than one packet to be sent, the PSH flag is used in the last packet to tell the server that the data must be pushed up to the receiving application immediately.

However, on a POST request, uploading a picture to imgur (e.g.), the PSH flag is present in every single chunk of payload until finished. I think, correct me if I'm wrong, this behaviour is just because every chunk of the transaction is big and must be sent to the upper layers as fast as possible to avoid a huge buffer and that this behaviour is used in real-time and interactive applications. But, is this an standard? Is this behaviour to be expected in every single POST request?

Thanks in advance

Comment: PSH asks TCP client end to send the communication immediately, and on the reciever to flush the buffer and to inform the application that the there is data waiting for it, rather than waiting on the applications threads to check for buffered data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"I think ... this behaviour is just because every chunk of the transaction is big and must be sent to the upper layers as fast as possible to avoid a huge buffer and that this behaviour is used in real-time and interactive applications"

The behavior you describe is determined by the sending client (software).  A common misconception about TCP & UDP implementations is that there is only one way to code, but there are choices to make when coding...and not all programmers make the same choices.  The RFCs are your friend.

http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1122/88.htm
"When an application issues a series of SEND calls without setting the PUSH flag, the TCP MAY aggregate the data internally without sending it. Similarly, when a series of segments is received without the PSH bit, a TCP MAY queue the data internally without passing it to the receiving application."

The *MAY* in that sentence offers the programmer (of the sending client) the choice of whether or not to set the PSH bit.  In the case you describe, the programmer chose to prioritize sending the payload up the stack to the application over buffering a series of them to send up the stack at once.

Hope that helps.